# Unexpected Token = getting while running the following code

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the following error while running the below. The issue is with the unexpected toke "=". Due to which I'm getting the error.

```
# ./yarn install
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/in-install/workspace/yarn-bin/yarn-1.15.2.js:1227
var _ref27 = (0, (_asyncToGenerator2 || _load_asyncToGenerator()).default)(function* (dir,relativeDir, ignoreBasenames = new Set()) {


SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:140:18)
at node.js:1043:3

Nodejs version 4.8.3
```

Comment: `function* (dir,relativeDir, ignoreBasenames = new Set())` I've never saw variable assignation used as parameter for a function, and I'd try to create the variable before.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in this StackOverflow question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564072/node-js-unexpected-token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function* (dir,relativeDir, ignoreBasenames = new Set()` uses default parameters.

Node.js 4.8.3 does not support default parameters for functions.  You will need to use at least Node.js 6.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters