# How to include js function with import in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing firebase cloud function:

```
const {getContactObject} = require('../../../../src/modules/Contacts/scenes/Contactlist/ContactsManager/functions/getContactObject')

const getApiResponsible = require('../../functions/getApiResponsible')

const createContact = async payload => {
  console.log('payload', payload)
  console.log(getContactObject(getApiResponsible()))
}

module.exports = createContact
```

My function with name **getContactObject** is located in src folder of the project, and its using es6 import/export

**getContactObject.js**

```
import { getCurDateWithUser } from '../../../../../../utilities/date/getCurDateWithUser'

export const getContactObject = uid => {
  return {
    lastName: '',
    name: '',
    middleName: '',
    gender: '',
    phone: [],
    email: [],
    messangers: [],
    social: [],
    address: [],
    dates: [],
    leads: [],
    sales: [],
    responsible: '',
    created: getCurDateWithUser(uid),
    updated: getCurDateWithUser(uid),
  }
}
```

How can i use it in my firebase cloud function, that's using node js 8?

Is it possible to import **getContactObject** function without rewriting it?

Now i'm having errors about imports:

[image: Errors log]

Comment: This seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564072/node-js-unexpected-token

Comment: Please try removing the spaces between the curly bruckets and the `getCurDateWithUser` so it would be like `import {getCurDateWithUser} from`. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Rewrite the following line:

```js
import { getCurDateWithUser } from '../../../../../../utilities/date/getCurDateWithUser'
```

to

```js
const getCurDateWithUser = require('../../../../../../utilities/date/getCurDateWithUser')
```

2. Use [Typescript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript). In your `tsconfig.json` make sure to set

```js
{
  //...
  "compilerOptions": {
        //..
        "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```