# HEROKU/NODEJS Build Fail with Mongodb module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, web-deployment

I am having an issue when deploying on Heroku, my app is working with Express and Mongodb, when using the repo that is functional on a local development on Heroku I encounter an error while tailing the logs that is within the module of Mongodb itself, how do I fix this?

[Heres the log: CTRL+CLICK TO SEE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4favZ.png)

[With this error on Heroku CTRL+CLICK TO SEE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWdAh.png)

This seems to be a module syntax error, which is doubtful, what's happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: [It looks like you're using code that needs to be compiled to an older version of JavaScript, e.g. TypeScript or a newer version of ECMAScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51564072/354577). You should have a build script in your `package.json` that does that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Engine node compability with Mongodb version on package.json, fixed by [upgrading to 16.16.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) with [Mongodb 4.10.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)..

For any other researchers who come across this, check NodeJs Mongodb compability on Google [for more information](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility/)

Thank you both.

Cheers

Comment: Add a link to the doc you are referring is more usefull

Comment: Say no more. =)